# Removing stubborn SVG background

Tags: inkscape, svg, transparency, png

I have an SVG file made by someone else, which I'd like to insert into Powerpoint such that its background (the white pixels in the image below) appears transparent and reveals the content in the layer below.

Exporting the SVG as PNG in Inkscape 1.2.1 doesn't result in an image with transparent background. Likewise if I convert to PNG using converters available online.

I found various suggestions on this site for how to remove backgrounds in Inkscape for SVGs, e.g. tick the Checkerbox option under Document Properties, or doing a Select All + Ungroup; but none worked.

Image preview is below, SVG file is [here](https://we.tl/t-5Gp2Q91yxs).
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVGs don't technically have a background normally, so it must be an object that has been added by the person who made it.

I downloaded your file, and I can see the problem. There's a white filled rectangle under the artwork, and it is also grouped with the artwork.

To fix it:

1. Select the artwork using the Select tool <kbd>S</kbd>
2. Do <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to ungroup it
3. Click somewhere off the side of the page. This will deselect everything.
4. Switch on the *Checkerboard* option in *File > Document Properties*. The checkerboard pattern shows where it is transparent.
5. The white rectangle is the same size as the page, so select it near the edge of the page, then you can delete it using <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

You should see the checkered bacgkround appear where previously there was white (see below). So, now when you export as PNG, there will be no background

[image]